# Throwing null pointer exception when accessing property of the domain object

Tags: grails

Inside a controller i just test these two lines. RaceRegistration domain has a property compositeEvent. So, i access the Registration domain first and then access the compositeevent using .compositeEvent.

```
println (RaceRegistration.get(r.toLong()))
println (RaceRegistration.get(r.toLong())).compositeEvent
```

The following error is thrown. As you can see the first print succeeds i.e it gets the Registration domain but the second println fails. My question is why is it throwing null pointer when we are certain that the RaceRegistration domain was accessed successfully.

```
com.runnercard.registration.RaceRegistration : 8
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver: NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [POST] /roadrace/message/sendEmail - parameters:
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null is null. Don't doubt this: it is true.

The 'void' `println` expression evaluates to null and the failing code is roughly equivalent to the following:

```
x = println (RaceRegistration.get(r.toLong()))
// x is null - so the following results in a NullPointerException
x.compositeEvent
```

It is probable that the parenthesis is merely in the wrong spot ([or even over-specified](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_omitting_parentheses)):

```
println (RaceRegistration.get(r.toLong()).compositeEvent)
// -or
println RaceRegistration.get(r.toLong()).compositeEvent
```